# Accessing spring bean from logging appender class

Tags: spring, log4j

I have log4j DailyRollingFileAppender class in which setFile() method I need to check database value to decide which file to used for logging.

```
DailyRollingFileAppender class 

public void setFileName()
{
    isLoginEnabled = authenticationManager.checkLoginLogging();
}
```

Here 'authenticationManager' is object of class used to make database call using spring dependency injection feature.

```
spring-beans.xml
<bean id="dailyRollingFileAppender" class="com.common.util.DailyRollingFileAppender">
 <property name="authenticationManager">
     <ref bean="authenticationManager"/>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.security.impl.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
    <property name="userService">
        <ref bean="userService"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

Now when I start my application log4j gets initiated first and since spring-beans is yet to invoked it throws NullPointerException in method setFileName(). 
So is there a way I can make call to 'authenticationManager.checkLoginLogging();' from DailyFileAppender class so that when log4j loads it should able to get database value?

Answer (score 17):

A few years late, but I hope this is of help to someone.

I was after similar functionality - I have a custom appender, and i wanted to use an autowired bean to perform some logging using a service we'd built. By making the appender implement the ApplicationContextAware interface, and making the field that i'd normally autowire static, i'm able to inject the spring-controlled bean into the instance of the appender that log4j has instantiated.

```
@Component
public class SslErrorSecurityAppender extends AppenderSkeleton implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static SecurityLogger securityLogger;

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        securityLogger.log(new SslExceptionSecurityEvent(SecurityEventType.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable(), "Unexpected SSL error"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        this.closed = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        if (applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("securityLogger") != null) {
            securityLogger = (SecurityLogger) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("securityLogger");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me! It takes some time to initialize Spring, so first bulk of logs are not being processed due to **securityLogger == null**, so it is good to add also:

`code
@Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (securityLogger != null {}
    }`

Comment: I'm curious how this works exactly. When I attempt it I get a double initialization. The first `SslErrorSecurityAppender` is initialized by Log4j, and the appcontext setter is never called. Then Spring kicks in, initializes `SslErrorSecurityAppender` a second time, but is never used because log4j is using the first instance.

Comment: @Casey this is how it works exactly. The log4j creates the `SslErrorSecurityAppender` using `new` operator and then Spring creates another instance of `SslErrorSecurityAppender` using bean instantiation. When Spring creates it's own `SslErrorSecurityAppender` instance, it automatically calls `setApplicationContext` method on it. And what this method do? It just gets the `SecurityLogger` bean from Spring's application context and assigns it to `static` field. The **static** is the key here. At this point, even instance, created by log4j can read the same static field value.

Comment: Actually, this example is some over-complicated, because you can just use setter autowiring like this `@Autowire public void setSecurityLogger(SecurityLogger securityLogger) { SslErrorSecurityAppender.securityLogger = securityLogger; }`.