# Trigger custom method when log4j2's logger.error() is triggered in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I am using Spring Boot with log4j2 - and I'd like to trigger a custom method in a '@Service' class when `logger.error(...)` is triggered.

For example,

```
@Service
public class Foo {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
    ...
    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error!", e); // When `error` is triggered...
        }
    }
}

// Other class
@Service
public class Bar {
    @Autowired private NotificationService notificationService;

    public void triggeredOnError() { // I'd like to trigger this method
        this.notificationService.notifySomething();
    }
}
```

I'd like to know this is possible in log4j2 with Spring Boot.  The thing is, I just want to trigger the default method `logger.error(...)` since **I don't want to change the default behavior of log4j2**.  I researched a bit - and `filter` or `adapter` might be the solution here, but I am not really sure how to achieve this. Please help me out!

Comment: Is it ok for you to use Java logging util instead of Log4j?

Comment: If yes, I have a way for your scenario, and BTW Java logging util (jdk 11) is completely similar to log4j

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad To say java.util.logging is completely similar to log4j is nonsense. jul doesn't support Markers, doesn't support parameterized format Strings, only supports logging Strings instead of Messages as Log4j does,  doesn't come with more than a couple of Handlers, doesn't have the equivalent of a Thread Context aka MDC and many more things. Furthermore, all performance tests show jul's performance is terrible and integrating other logging frameworks with it is very hard.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and the question can have many valid answers and the "best" one would be mostly a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While an appender would work as Mark suggests, I would implement a Filter. A Filter can be placed in four different locations in Log4j 2 and has the option of forcing the log event to be logged, forcing it to not be logged or just continue on with the normal evaluation of whether it should be logged. But a filter can always be configured with onMatch=NEUTRAL and onMismatch=NEUTRAL so that it really has no effect on whether the log event is processed but allows some other processing to take place. In addition, Filters are much easier to write than an Appender.

You can find a sample Filter at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Filters

What you should not do in a Filter though, is use it as a way to write the log event to some destination. That is exactly what Appenders are for.

Comment: I see - so what I want to use is `filter` - thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way to achieve that is to create a special appender and in Log4j2 configuration associate it with a logger of your choice (or maybe with all the loggers if you want a “global” configuration).

Then you could use an “appender filter” to make an appender called only if its an error message.

The only potential issue is contacting the spring bean from log4j2 appender. Read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275171/accessing-spring-bean-from-logging-appender-class/30585242) to understand how technically you can achieve that.

The benefit of this method is that you don’t change the framework but instead leverage the configuration options that it already provides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your answer is also helpful as well!