# Autowiring email sender bean into another bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, java-ee-6

I am using spring 3.x version and am using annotations to wire the dependencies. I have two beans as below.

```
package com.sample.project.service;
@Component
public class MyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton{


     //here trying to inject emailSender bean
    @Autowired
    private EmailSender emailSender;

//some code with emailSender
//emailSender.callSomeService...


}
```

**Above bean extends AppenderSkeleton class of log4j.**

```
package com.sample.project.service;
@Component
public class EmailSender {

  @Autowired
  private SomeOtherBean someOther;

//somecode

}
```

I have an entry in applicationContext.xml as below.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.project.service" />
```

### Log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <!-- Appenders -->

    <appender name="stdout" class="com.sample.project.service.MyAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But the problem is, `emailSender` injected into `MyAppender` is always `null`.
Am i doing anything wrong here. Or is there any problem with overriding `log4j`specific classes and annotating them with `@Component` ?   Thanks! Please help me!

Comment: There is no way it can be `null` unless you are creating your `MyAppender` object yourself.

Comment: No. I am not creating MyAppender object. It is already annotated with @Component.

Comment: Show us where and how you are injecting it then.

Comment: MyAppender is already annotated with @Component.

Comment: Ok, so it exists as a bean in your context. How are you using it?

Comment: MyAppender is automatically called when log.info is logged. I have a switch statement inside MyAppender and that switch statement is being executed but emailSender is coming as null..

Comment: You are confused. A Spring bean won't just register itself with your `log4j` configuration.

Comment: It is registering and the bean is detectable. Because i am able to execute other logic in MyAppender.

Comment: That's what I've been asking you, show us where you use it.

Comment: Because i have log4j.xml config as <appender name="stdout" class="com.sample.project.service.MyAppender">
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
 </appender>

Comment: whenever in the code i use log.info then MyAppender is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this config

```
<appender name="stdout" class="com.sample.project.service.MyAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

log4j is creating its own `MyAppender` instance. This instance has nothing to do with the `@Component` instance that Spring creates. As such, there is no autowiring being done and your field is initialized to `null` by default.

Comment: Please suggest me any alternative here.somehow i need emailSender instance in MyAppender.Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 There is no simple alternative. `log4j` sets itself up with `static` initializers. Spring runs after that. You can do something [like what is described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324053/configure-log4j-to-log-to-custom-file-at-runtime) by specifying to `root` logger. Until that's done, `log4j` will be using what's in your config file.

Comment: @user755806 `ApplicationContextAware` will only make it aware of Springs `ApplicationContext` it's being created it. It still has nothing to do with log4j. You're kind of out of luck. [Try this while you are at it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592399/change-log4j-properties-at-runtime)

Comment: @Stirios, Thanks much. I will try by following the above. Meanwhile if you get some time please throw some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 [Found this too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730634/what-are-the-available-options-to-retrieve-spring-managed-beans-in-a-log4j-appen) These are your only real options :(

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try all the links you suggested. Please give me any good approach if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Stirios, I accepted the answer. Please give me some ideas if you get. Thanks..Please help me...