# Autowired spring bean to custom slf4j appender

Tags: java, spring

Using AspectJ I've injected service into non-managed domain object:
This is service:

```
@Service
public class DomainServiceImpl implements DomainService { 
     public String getLoggerMessage(String prevMessage) {
            return String.format("Message from logger service:%s", prevMessage);
    }
}
```

This is domain object:

```
@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
public class DomainObject {
    private IAppenderService appenderService;
    @Autowired
    public void setAppenderService(IAppenderService appenderService) {
        this.appenderService = appenderService;
    }
    public IAppenderService getAppenderService() {
        return appenderService;
    }   

    public String formMessage(String message){      
        return appenderService.getLoggerMessage(message);
    }   
}
```

Following test was successfull:

```
@Test
    public void testAppender(){
        DomainObject domainObject = new DomainObject();
        assertNotNull(domainObject.getAppenderService());
    }
```

and if I add

```
System.out.println(new DomainObject().formMessage("test message"));
```

to any controller i've got expected string in console:
"Message from logger service:test message"

Then I try use this service into custom slf4j appender:

```
@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
public class MyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {  
    IAppenderService    appenderService;        
    @Autowired
    public void setAppenderService(IAppenderService appenderService) {
        this.appenderService = appenderService;
    }
    public IAppenderService getAppenderService() {
        return appenderService;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {       
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {     
        System.out.println(new DomainObject().formMessage(event.getMessage().toString()));
    }
}
```

but gotta the NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sbk.spring.testaopjc.domain.DomainObject.formMessage(DomainObject.java:19)
    at sbk.spring.testaopjc.appender.MyAppender.append(MyAppender.java:29)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
```

at same time following test was successfull:

```
public void testAppendeSecond(){
        MyAppender appender = new MyAppender();
        assertNotNull(appender.getAppenderService());
    }
```

Can anybody explain me why MyAppender behaves differently in this cases?
PS:My log4j.properties file:

```
 log4j.rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT

 log4j.appender.STDOUT=sbk.spring.testaopjc.appender.MyAppender
 log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Looks like this appender is created before Spring loads its classes, thus getting your exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occuring  because log4j is being bootstrapped before Spring.

The following answer may help with providing a possible solution for the issue:

[log4j - Accessing spring bean from logging appender class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275171/accessing-spring-bean-from-logging-appender-class/30585242#30585242)

Answer (score 0):

This idea has been discussed before, maybe not in the exact same configuration, but somewhat similar. Basically, it's about using something Spring-managed in a log4j powered environment. And is not easy to do because the log4j stuff is initialized before Spring.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730634/what-are-the-available-options-to-retrieve-spring-managed-beans-in-a-log4j-appen) another discussion on a similar subject.